# How can I increase the thickness of the x and y axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I increase the thickness of the x and y axis?

```
\definecolor{bfffqq}{rgb}{0.7490196078431373,1.,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.22123893805309733cm,y=0.23255813953488372cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.22123893805309733cm,y=0.23255813953488372cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-14.566370614359172,
xmax=9.283185307179586,
ymin=-12.0,
ymax=9.5,
xtick={0},
ytick={0},]
\clip(-12.666370614359172,-12.) rectangle (6.483185307179586,9.5);
\draw[line width=0.pt,color=bfffqq,fill=bfffqq,fill opacity=1.0, smooth,samples=50,domain=-12.566370614359172:-9.42477796076938] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)}) -- (-9.42477796076938,0.) -- (-12.566370614359172,0.) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=0.pt,color=bfffqq,fill=bfffqq,fill opacity=1.0, smooth,samples=50,domain=-9.42477796076938:-6.283185307179586] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)}) -- (-6.283185307179586,0.) -- (-9.42477796076938,0.) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=0.pt,color=bfffqq,fill=bfffqq,fill opacity=1.0, smooth,samples=50,domain=-6.283185307179586:-3.141592653589793] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)}) -- (-3.141592653589793,0.) -- (-6.283185307179586,0.) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=0.pt,color=bfffqq,fill=bfffqq,fill opacity=1.0, smooth,samples=50,domain=-3.141592653589793:0.0] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)}) -- (0.,0.) -- (-3.141592653589793,0.) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=0.pt,color=bfffqq,fill=bfffqq,fill opacity=1.0, smooth,samples=50,domain=0.0:3.141592653589793] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)}) -- (3.141592653589793,0.) -- (0.,0.) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=0.pt,color=bfffqq,fill=bfffqq,fill opacity=1.0, smooth,samples=50,domain=3.141592653589793:6.283185307179586] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)}) -- (6.283185307179586,0.) -- (3.141592653589793,0.) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-12.566370614359172:6.283185307179586] plot(\x,{(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Where di you find that code?  `plot(\x,{Eğer(-4*3.141592653589793*≤*(\x)*≤*2*3.141592653589793,*(\x)*sin(((\x))*180/pi))})` is not anything that can work...

Comment: After drawing the shape in geogebra program, there is generate code and I found it there. So how do I plot the x*sin(x) function in the closed interval [-4pi,2pi]?

Comment: "if", do you have the this code in latex?

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: Still: `If(-4*3.141592653589793≤x≤2*3.141592653589793,x*sin(((\x))180/pi))})` is not LaTeX. You have to use `ifthenelse` (page 1024 of the Ti*k*Z manual).

Comment: Understood. I edited the code. How can I increase the thickness of the x and y axis in the code I shared?

Comment: You removed the preamble and now your snippet is not an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Anyway, I added a hint for the axis thickness...

Comment: Hi! Since you are new to this site, please take the time and have a look at this short introduction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour. In addition, carefully read the post https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 (already mentioned by user Rmano),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why GeoGebra generates that code (never used it); it is using strange functions and a very strange structure. Generally, I think that using `pgfplots` or similar things is to have a document where the graphs are structured and changeable in the document itself; importing things with strange numbers is not useful at all --- much better, in this case, to generate a PDF and `includegraphics` it.

Anyways, you can start with this:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-4*pi, xmax=2*pi,
            domain=-4*pi:2*pi,
            samples=301,
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            enlarge x limits,
            enlarge y limits,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            clip mode = individual,
            ]
            \addplot[thick, blue] {x*sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add `axis line style = {ultra thick},` to have:

[image]

And to fill and add a node:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-4*pi, xmax=2*pi,
            domain=-4*pi:2*pi,
            samples=301,
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            enlarge x limits,
            enlarge y limits,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            axis line style = {ultra thick},
            clip mode = individual,
            ]
            \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);% invisible path
            \addplot[thick, blue, name path=f] {x*sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot[green] fill between[of=f and axis];
            \node at (-2.5*pi, 1) {$\mathbf{\pi}$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good. So, can we color the region between the curve and the x-axis?

Comment: You can search this site for `fillbetween` ...

Comment: Yes it's okay. I want to show only -4pi and 2pi points in the coordinate system, how can I do it?

Comment: https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfplots/0 , section 4.15, "Tick options"

Comment: Thank you again for your helps and for coloring

Comment: I have one last question left. The x-axis is under the green zone as you added it last. How can we bring it up?

Comment: A rapid google search "pgfplots fillbetween axis" gives: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448500/38080. Basically, add `axis on top`

Comment: Yes i did it. Thanks. But I couldn't make the -4pi and 2pi points symbolically on the axes.

Comment: If you read the manal at the link I gave you, `xtick={-4*pi, 2*pi},xticklabels={$-4\pi$,$2\pi$}` --- at page 348 you have exactly this example... and now, please, if you have more questions, a) upvote or mark this question as answered, and b) ask another question, that is how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: How can I mark as answered?

Comment: @HakanBaşarı You can "accept" an answer by clicking the **checkmark** symbol on the left side of the answer (next to the points counter if the question with the up/down arrow).